# Python: ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

Currently trying to change date, im doing it in a for loop over a list of items, this is the code:

```
new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y')
```

This is the input and ouput.

```
Old Date: 2021-09-01
 New date: 01/09/21
Old Date: 2021-09-01
 New date: 01/09/21
Old Date: 2021-09-01
 New date: 01/09/21
Old Date: 2021-08-30
 New date: 30/08/21
Old Date: 2021-07-20
 New date: 20/07/21
Old Date: 2021-07-12
 New date: 12/07/21
Old Date: 2021-06-21
 New date: 21/06/21
```

Everything seems to work fine but it still gives me error:

```
 raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Because of this error I cannot add the new_date into my json to dump the data with new date.

Comment: What do you mean it still gives you error? The list of output you pasted seem to work. What input produced the wrong result?

Answer (score 1):

There is an item in your list that is empty (`''`). Filter your list first:

```py
list = [date for date in list if date]
```

And then execute the loop.

Comment: Good find :) But don't name variables as `list` because that is a builtin.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano I know, but since I did not know the name of your list I tried to make it as clear as possible ;).